# Creating a EntityIterable from multiple Entity objects

Tags: java, geospatial, xodus

I'm trying to implement a "nearby" filter with Xodus, having this code:

```java
AtomicReference<EntityIterable> referenceToScope = ...;
PropertyNearbyCondition propertyNearbyCondition = (PropertyNearbyCondition) entityCondition;
String propertyName = propertyNearbyCondition.propertyName();
Double longitude = propertyNearbyCondition.longitude();
Double latitude = propertyNearbyCondition.latitude();
Double distance = propertyNearbyCondition.distance();
EntityIterable entities =
    referenceToScope.get().intersect(txn.findWithProp(entityType, propertyName));
List<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<>();
entities.forEach(entity -> {
  GeoPoint reference = (GeoPoint) entity.getProperty(propertyName);
  double instantaneousDistance =
      MathHelper.distFrom(latitude, longitude, reference.getLatitude(),
  reference.getLatitude());
  if (distance >= instantaneousDistance) {
    entityList.add(entity);
  }
});


EntityIterable scoped = referenceToScope.get().intersect(build(entityList));
```

```java
EntityIterable build(List<Entity> entityList) {
   // TODO: Build a new EntityIterable from the entityList
}
```

The algorithm may not be the best, but, the main question here is how to build a new `EntityIterable` based from multiple Entity objects? Is that possible?

My solution to basically collect "nearby" entities is to iterate over all entities with the custom `GeoPoint` property then for each Entity found, comparing the distance of its GeoPoint property and if that is a hit then all these entities should be collected into one `EntityIterable.`

**How do you build a `EntityIterable` from a list of `Entity` objects?**

**UPDATE:**

**Explaining how this works step-by-step:**

This code below gets all the entities with the given property name, e.g. `geoLocation`

```java
EntityIterable entities =
    referenceToScope.get().intersect(txn.findWithProp(entityType, propertyName));
```

Then for all the entities with such geoLocation property for example iterate over it to compute if it meets the distance target:

```java
List<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<>();
entities.forEach(entity -> {
   // compute the distance target
});
```

Adding the *entity* to the new `List` if it meets the target.

From here what needs to be done is to either remove all entities in the `EntityIterable entities` which does not equal to the ID's of the matched *entities* in the `entityList` OR to intersect these matched entities to `referenceToScope.get()` and not to `EntityIterable entities` (just to avoid confusion, this `entities` *iterable* is a just a temp one)

Comment: p.s. would this approach be a performance issue with Xodus?

Comment: and the reason for creating a `EntityIterable` is to create a scoped context, as this code is just part of a chain of other property conditions that are basically under the same scope of  `EntityIterable`, e.g. this is chained with `PropertyLocalTimeRangeCondition -> PropertyNearbyCondition -> PropertyMinMaxCondition`

Comment: Why are you doing `referenceToScope.get().intersect(build(entityList))`? entityList is already an intersection with referenceToScope, right? If you don't have to intersect result or to do any other operation with it, then probably you don't have to build EntityIterable from the result?

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov `entityList` is a computed subset of this `EntityIterable entities =
    referenceToScope.get().intersect(txn.findWithProp(entityType, propertyName));` because this one, the `entities` contains just all the Xodus entities that have the said propertyName it does not exclude entities that does not meet the target distance that is the main reason for generating a separate list. Unless we can compute within Xodus find methods if a given Geo Location is within a range. I'm trying but it seems impossible with the find min max method. So my solution is to compute from outside.

Comment: Please read carefully. There is no need to intersect smth with `referenceToScope.get()` twice. This `referenceToScope.get().intersect(build(entityList))` doesn't change the result (entityList). Therefore, in your code you don't need this `build()` function.  Generally, 99.99% of cases of calculations over EntityStore can be expressed as two-step process: 1) prepare `EntityIterable` instance using API; 2) manually filter the result (in you case filter points). After that you no loner need an EntityIterable, serialize the result (list)  as a network output or whatever.

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov yes correct, `build()` is irrelevant now based on the answer below, intersecting to a singleton iterable was the solution. However the reason for keeping the "EnityIterable" in context, it is a scope that is used by a chain of other more conditions, check to get the idea: https://github.com/divroll/datafactory/blob/d8d9c6abc97fced439ba53ac5aaab6fa8d117cf1/src/main/java/com/divroll/datafactory/Unmarshaller.java#L152

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how to solve this:

```java
entities.forEach(entity -> {
  GeoPoint reference = (GeoPoint) entity.getProperty(propertyName);
  double instantaneousDistance =
      MathHelper.distFrom(latitude, longitude, reference.getLatitude(),
  reference.getLatitude());
  if (distance < instantaneousDistance) {
    referenceToScope.set(referenceToScope.get().minus(txn.getSingletonIterable(entity)));
  }
});
```

This will effectively remove all entities that fails to match the target distance.

Comment: Yes, you can also use `union` of singletons, but this is basically a bad idea due to possible performance impact. I'm trying to explain the author that in most cases there is no need to transaform result represented as `List<Entity>` to `EntityIterable`.

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov if not intersecting with `getSingletonIterable` how can you achieve the removal of unmatched entities, I would like to know. Perhaps you can post an answer also?